# Could not load type

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

First of all i thank you on your time and i hope that you can understand me even with English as broken as this one:

> Could not load type
>   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IDbContextOptionsExtensionWithDebugInfo'
>   from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=3.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'

Tried to reinstall all packages, to manually put references, restarted PC,restarted VS2019 and even started new project but still error is there again.

I've been [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/578622/could-not-load-type-microsoftentityframeworkcorein.html) but it didn't help.

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(


Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

--.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <UserSecretsId>aspnet-ZavrsniRad01-F04B6A7E-6450-4254-8092-F42843F4615A</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>


  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.0-preview6.19307.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.0-preview6.19307.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="3.0.0-preview6.19307.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.0.0-preview.18572.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.0.0-preview6.19304.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="3.0.0-preview6.19304.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="3.0.0-preview6-19319-03" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: show your `packages.config` and your `.csproj` files

Comment: Have you seen this? https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/15192

Comment: I've put .csproj, but couldn't find package.config  the error occurred when i tried to add secont DbContext into StartUp file.

Comment: @jefftroman I've updated my efc sql to 3.0 and the result is the same.

Answer (score 8):

Apparently i had to install EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer preview6 to solve this error

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -Version 3.0.0-preview6.19304.10
```

Comment: This fixed my problem too. Thanks! I posted this in the github issue thread to help others. https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/issues/3698

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with my test project and I saw that the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` was missing from my test packages, so I installed the latest version of it and my issue was resolved.

**Note:** If you are having the same issue with a test do make sure that the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory` version matches the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` just for consistency.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I also had this error message but the root cause was a missing proxies package related to lazy loading.  Installing Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies fixed the issue for me:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies -Version 3.1.8
```